cs50.h in windows gcc guide
Can anyone help me to include cs50.h in VS code. I have windows but there is no option for Windows. I have searched so much but couldn't find anything. Can anyone please guide me from zero to install or setup cs50.h in my windows. please help me.
I want to include cs50.h in my c files.

SImple way. Put cs50.h and cs50.c in the same directory as the rest of your source code. Use #include "cs50.h" where you need it and add cs50.c to your build command like gcc mycode.c cs50.c -o myprogram.exe How you change the compile command will vary depending on which plugin you are using to compile your code.

how can i use it with 'make' command and run check50 and submit50

i have placed cs50.h and cs50.c in both 1 - c folder and world sub folder but it still shows error
PS F:\Downloadf\cs50\1 - C\world> gcc hello.c cs50.c -o hello.exe
hello.c:2:10: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <cs50.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Okay. I said put it in the same folder with the rest of your source code and use #include "cs50.h", not #include <cs50.h>.

If you want the full environment locally you can use docker as explained here: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/cs50.dev/
